# Not able to use the regular expression in Survey response validation - ^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$

Tags: validation, regular-expressions, salesforce-survey

I am trying to add a validation in Salesforce survey response. User should be able to enter numbers up to 2 decimal places.

Allowed inputs,
12
12.3
12.34

I am trying with **^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$** but I am getting error "The validation formulas specified in the following questions are invalid: Page 6 Question 1. Correct the formulas and try again."

I have tried same using validation rule and it gives syntax error there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with pipe expression and it is working fine now. [0-9]+|[0-9]+[.][0-9]|[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The dot character in regular expression syntax matches *all* characters. You need to escape it if you want to math a literal dot. Corrected version:

```
^\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Adrian. The expression doesn't throw any syntax error but it is not allowing the user to enter numbers or decimals. It is expecting \ in the input